# SQL Server FETCH NEXT X ONLY based on a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination

I have a request to get some online courses.

This is an example of results I can get :

```
course_code | course_date | participant_name
------------+-------------+------------------
21175A      | 2021-12-01  | Jon Doe
21175A      | 2021-12-01  | Lisa Tia
21175A      | 2021-13-01  | Jon Doe
21175A      | 2021-13-01  | Lisa Tia
```

As you can see, I get multiple rows for the same course depending on the dates and the participants, so I have to do some process in PHP to put everything in an array with keys (`course_code`)

I want to make a pagination to get the 25 first courses (and not rows)

```
SELECT course_code, course_date, participant_name 
FROM courses
ORDER BY course_date
OFFSET 0
FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY
```

This won't work because a course can take multiple rows (4 here). So I wonder if I can write a query to get the 25 first courses (based on the column course_code) even if there are 100 rows.

Do you have an idea ? Thank you in advance

EDIT : This is what I did :

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT course_code
    FROM courses
    WHERE course_date <= '2021-12-31'
    ORDER BY course_code
    OFFSET 0 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT * 
FROM courses
INNER JOIN cte ON cte.course_code = courses.course_code
WHERE course_date <= '2021-12-31'
```

I added the `WHERE` clause in both to make the request slower

Comment: Get your 25 courses using a CTE first and then join to it for the remaining data

Comment: @Stu Yes thank you that is what I did !

Comment: If you are doing pagination for performance reasons, you may want to look at [Keyset Pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset), which is far more performant than paging by row-number

Answer (score 1):

Use `DENSE_RANK`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY course_code) dr
    FROM courses
)

SELECT course_code, course_date, participant_name
FROM cte
WHERE dr <= 25
ORDER BY course_date;
```

For the pagination part, just change the inequality in the `WHERE` clause.  For example, to get the second page of 25 courses per page, you would use `WHERE dr > 25 AND dr <= 50`.

Comment: EDIT : It works but the problem is that the query takes the same time as the original query. That is not exactly what I am looking for, if it's not slower I can do some process in PHP for the pagination

Comment: @ErwanPLB - you probably should be handling this in your front end.

Comment: @ErwanPLB An index on `(course_code, course_date, participant_name)` might speed up my answer.  The final two columns can also appear inside `INCLUDE` and not be part of the B tree.